# Does Akka ask pattern get rid of timed out message on target actor's mailbox?

Tags: akka

Assume that I have 2 actors, A and B, A ask B for a response within a 10 seconds timeout. After that B still busy processing other messages which cannot response for A within 10 seconds, so `Future` in actor A get timeout exception.

The questions are:

1) After actor A got exception, does the message that A send to B still be inside B's mailbox waiting for B to process it?

2) If yes, how to prevent/detect B form overwhelm of messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is that yes, the message is still in B's box. This is quite a common misconception about `Future`s in many contexts like the ask pattern, where you have some request going on represented by a future that times out after a limited amount of time; most people would assume that this would mean that when the process being awaited would be cancelled but there is no way that a generic abstraction like a `Future` could do it (also remember that `Future` ≠ `Thread`).

As for the second question the answer is that there is no easy answer and you need to think about a strategy that fits your environment. If all your actors reside in the same VM you could embed timestamps in your messages to validate them on the target actor; this would still be racy as the actor B could take enough time to process the message to trigger the timeout on the A side, generating inconsistency (i.e. A thinks that the operation failed, B things that it succeeded).

Otherwise, in a distributed environment, an idea could be to send a *compensating action* to the actor B when the actor A detects a timeout. You may want to have a look at the **Saga Pattern** (you can find a nice talk [here](http://gotocon.com/chicago-2015/presentation/Applying%20the%20Saga%20Pattern)) if you are doing such a distributed system based on actors and you are having troubles with this sort of situations. In any case, just remember that distributed systems are hard and there is no silver bullet or any way around studying hard to get them right.